# Finding the user defined members of an object

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I am trying to create a function that performs a deep copy of c# objects by using Reflection.
till now, I have been able to do that for arrays, but in case of Objects, how do I get to differentiate between user defined members and system defined members ?

Comment: What is your definition of user defined members and system defined members?

Comment: there is no such thing as "user defined members vs system defined"

Comment: Oh, I mean the user-defined classes/constructs(that would be known only at runtime) vs the primitives and CLS.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by making the distinction between "system" and "non-system"? How will "system" members be treated differently?

Comment: By differentiating, I'll be able to exert control over where to copy recursively. If my copy function encounters a System.* object, I'll simply pass its reference. but on primitives, the values would be copied.

Comment: BTW, I am porting an existing java method when this encountered. So, my approach might be wrong. Please comment if this seems to be the case